# Proof of derivative of the inverse function

Tags: calculus

[image]

I want to know if there are any "gaps" in my reasoning on this proof or anything I could make better .
How can I show that when delta x approches zero is equivalent with delta y approches zero ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since $f$ is assumed to be differentiable, we also have that $f$ is continuous. Therefore, $\Delta y \to 0$ as $\Delta x \to 0$ and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks, something else appears to be unclear now , isnt the last step the derivative at y_1 ? not exactly what I should show ?

Comment: Had to stare for a little bit, I'm getting a touch tripped up by $x=f(y)$ and $y=f^{-1}(y)$. That being said, it looks correct: we have successfully related the derivative of $f^{-1}(x)$ to the derivative of $f(y)$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation for what we're trying to proove

Comment: There is a lamentable lack of hypotheses presented here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just show that if f is differentiable so is its invers , either analytically or geometrically.

Also explain why when delta x approches 0 so does delta y.

The rest looks perfect